# Remove even numbers from a vector in c++

Tags: c++

can somebody help me with this function: suppose that I need to remove all even numbers from a vector using reference: can I do that? Is the push_back correct or should I use something else?

```cpp
void evenRemoe(vector<int>& arr) {
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
        if(arr[i] % 2 != 0) {
            push_back(arr[i]);
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to *push* something you are trying to *remove*?

Comment: No, push_back isn't right (and I expect you knew that, otherwise you wouldn't have used it, and wouldn't be here now). You may find the [erase-remove-if idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39019806/using-erase-remove-if-idiom) worth a read.

Answer (score 6):

Using `push_back` *adds* elements so that's not going to work.

You can use [`std::erase_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase2) with a functor, like a lambda or other function acting as a unary predicate, to decide what elements that should be removed.

```cpp
void evenRemoe(std::vector<int>& arr) {
    std::erase_if(arr, [](int i) { return i % 2 == 0; });
}
```

Prior to C++20 you could implement the erase–remove idiom

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
void evenRemoe(std::vector<int>& arr) {
    arr.erase(std::remove_if(arr.begin(), arr.end(),
                             [](int i) { return i % 2 == 0; }),
              arr.end());
}
```

Comment: Sidenote: It doesn't have to be a lambda. A regular function can also be used.

Comment: @eerorika true, updated

Answer (score 3):

No, `push_back()` is not the correct thing to use.  That is meant for *adding* values, not *removing* them.

Also, your code is actually looking for *odd* values, not *even* values.

You can use [`std::vector::erase()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) to remove individual values, eg:

```cpp
void evenRemoe(vector<int>& arr){
    for(size_t i = 0; i < arr.size();){
        if (arr[i] % 2 == 0){
            arr.erase(arr.begin()+i);
        }else{
            ++i;
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, consider using the [Erase-Remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom) via [`std::remove_if()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) and `std::vector::erase()`, eg:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>

void evenRemoe(vector<int>& arr){
    arr.erase(
        std::remove_if(arr.begin(), arr.end(),
            [](int value){ return (value % 2) == 0; }
        ),
        arr.end()
    );
}
```

Or, in C++20, via [`std::erase_if()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase2), eg:

```cpp
void evenRemoe(vector<int>& arr){
    std::erase_if(arr,
        [](int value){ return (value % 2) == 0; }
    );
}
```

Comment: There was a mistake in the original code - even integers are those that `(value % 2) == 0`.

Comment: @AndreySemashev fixed, thanks

Answer (score 3):

`push_back` is a method of [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for *appending* an element to the end of the vector, not *removing*. What you need is one of the `erase` methods.

However, you should be careful while erasing elements of the vector you're iterating over. Care must be taken to avoid incrementing the index when you remove the element.

The better way to do this is to use [`std::remove_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) algorithm instead of iterating the vector yourself.

```
void evenRemove(vector<int>& arr) {
    auto it = std::remove_if(arr.begin(), arr.end(),
        [](int n) { return (n % 2) == 0; });
    arr.erase(it, arr.end());
}
```

Despite the name, `std::remove_if` doesn't actually *remove* any elements from the vector. Instead, it moves the elements that match the predicate (in our case - all even integers) to the end of the vector and returns an iterator pointing to the first of such elements. Therefore, to actually remove the elements you need to call `erase` with the iterators denoting the tail of the vector that contains the even integers.

Answer (score 0):

From C++20 onwards you can use std::erase_if() , Prior to c++20 erase-remove idiom used to be the solution of this problem.

```
v.erase(std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), is_even), v.end());
```

Where is_even is a functor

Comment: Isn't it what Ted Lyngmo already suggested?

Answer (score 0):

Remove multiple element from vector using iterator.
Just take care that when we erase using iterator,it goes invalid.

```
int main(){
        vector<int> vec={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
        for(auto it=vec.begin();it!=vec.end();){
           if(*it%2==0)
               vec.erase(it);
           else
               it++;
        }
        for(auto i:vec){
            cout<<i<<" ";
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

output:1 3 5 7 9

2nd method

```
int main(){
    vector<int> vec={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    vec.erase(remove_if(vec.begin(),vec.end(),[](int i){
        return i%2==0;
    }),vec.end());

    for(auto i:vec)
        cout<<i<<" ";
    
    return 0;
}
```