# Find unique element in sorted array using c++

Tags: c++, arrays, sortedlist

I am trying to find unique element from the array these is question

```
Input  : arr[] = {1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5}
Output : arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

They give me correct output but why they give `0` at the end in output:

```
these is my output:
{1,2,3,4,5,0}
```

Code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5};
    int n=sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    int c=0;
    for(int j=0;j<=n;j++){
        if(arr[j]!=arr[j+1]){
            cout<<arr[j];
            }


    }
   
}
```

Comment: Have you tried [`std::unique`?](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique)

Comment: Your code invokes undefined behavior. `n` is the count of elements. Your loop caps on exceeding `n` (problem #1) and even if fixed you also index `j+1`. Both are wrong. Each causes a breach of your array; doing both just pours extra salt on the wound.

Comment: OT: don't use `sizeof` to determine the size of an array. Its too easy to use it wrong. Use `std::size` instead. In cases where `sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0])` produces meansingless results `std::size` fails to compile

Comment: ok I try that....

Comment: What you're probably shooting for is more along the lines of: output the first element (which will always be included). From there, loop on `j=1; j<n; ++j` and only output `arr[j]` when `arr[j-1] != arr[j]` is true.

Comment: @developer FYI -- [See std::unique and std::set](https://godbolt.org/z/1eaKrY3ha)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Except for `std::cout`, you code is much more C than ++.

- [`std::unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) of the C++ Standard Library does exactly what you want. There is no need to re-implement this.
- Next there is the [erase-remove idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39019806/using-erase-remove-if-idiom) to delete the superfluous elements.
- For the output, you can use [`std::for_each()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) or at least a [range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).
- And also, you [don't want `using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

A more modern solution looks like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
int main(){
    std::vector<int> arr {1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5};
    auto last = std::unique(arr.begin(), arr.end());
    arr.erase(last, arr.end());
    std::for_each(arr.begin(), arr.end(), [](int n){std::cout << n << std::endl;} );
}
```

[Try it on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/os3rWGWh7).

Answer (score 0):

problem is in for loop becouse you use less or equal to n.
you need to use just less then n becouse array starts from zero that means you asking for sixth element that do not have alocalizated in memory

now it should be correct

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5};
    int n=sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    int c=0;
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++) {
        if (arr[j]!=arr[j+1]) {
            cout<<arr[j];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In general when you see `<=` in the exit condition of a loop iterating a container, you're probably looking at an off-by-one bug. It's always worth stopping and inspecting the code more closely to make sure it is correct.

Comment: On the last iteration of your loop `arr[j+1]` reads past the end of the array.

Comment: Side note: as of C++17 use [`std::size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) in place of `int n=sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);`. It is simpler and will make common misuses brutally obvious by failing to compile. Before C++17 consider writing your own. [See the fourth possible implementation here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size#Possible_implementation).