# How do I use std::copy_if by both coping elements and removing those elements from the original container

Tags: c++, vector, c++20

Say I have a `std::vector<int>` with a simple operation to copy those elements which are even:

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    std::vector<int> even;
    std::copy_if(std::make_move_iterator(v.begin()), std::make_move_iterator(v.end()), std::back_inserter(even), [](int i){return i%2 == 0;});
        
    return 0;
}
```

My question how can I combine the above with any other method to remove the elements from vector `v` which was copied to vector `even`

Comment: There's [`std::remove_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove), are you trying to perform this in a single action/loop?

Comment: [Erase Remove If](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39019806/using-erase-remove-if-idiom)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would switch to using `std::remove_if` instead and have the function you pass to `remove_if` do the adding to the other vector.  That gives you

```
std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
std::vector<int> even;
v.erase(std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), 
                       [&](auto val){ bool cond = (val % 2 == 0); 
                       if (cond) even.push_back(val); return cond; }), v.end());
```

Comment: Are you not missing a v.end() as the last argument to the std::remove_if ?

Comment: @ATK Yep, that's what I get for not trying to compile it :)  Fixed now.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't recommend trying to use `std::copy_if` here. Instead use [`std::stable_partition`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition) to move even elements to the end of `v`, copy this part to `even` using the vector constructor and then erase the copied elements from `v`:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    
    // actual logic
    auto pivot = std::stable_partition(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int x) { return (x % 2) != 0;  });
    std::vector<int> even(pivot, v.end());
    v.erase(pivot, v.end());


    // display results
    std::cout << "v:\n";
    for (auto x : v)
    {
        std::cout << x << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << "even:\n";
    for (auto x : even)
    {
        std::cout << x << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For objects that are expensive to copy, you may want to use `std::move_iterator` when creating `even` as suggested in @MooningDucks answer:

```
std::vector<int> even(std::move_iterator(pivot), std::move_iterator(v.end()));
```